# ipython can't load module when using magic %load, but succeed when loading interactively

Tags: python-3.x, ipython

When I launch `ipython -i script_name` or load the script with `%load`, it fails loading `sklearn.ensamble`.
But it succeed in loading and I am able to use it when I launch `ipython` alone and then `from sklearn.ensamble import *`.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Shame on me, it was just a typo: the correct module is named `sklearn.ensemble`.